# Change output voice in C#

Tags: c#, text-to-speech

Hi I'm just testing SpeechSynthesizer in C# and I want to change the voice.

```
SpeechSynthesizer reader = new SpeechSynthesizer();


private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            reader.Dispose();
            reader = new SpeechSynthesizer();
            reader.SelectVoiceByHints(VoiceGender.Male);
            reader.Speak("Hi how are you baby");
        }
```

There is no more Code, just a single button(WinForm). Personally I would say that  `reader.SelectVoiceByHints(VoiceGender.Male);`should be enough. But if I click the button, I still will hear a female voice. What do I need to change? Thank you!

Comment: We need a lot more information. For example, what is and where did `SpeechSynthesizer` come from?

Comment: Might be irrelevant, but what .NET/Windows version are you running on?

Comment: I have edit the tags to use the more appropriate `text-to-speech` instead of `speech-recognition`

Comment: @FrankV I'm assuming it's the [`System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms586874(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

Comment: @DStanley, we *could* assume however that is to be specified.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange 4.5 / Win7

Comment: @DStanley you are right and thank you for the edit.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to selected specific voices like this:

```
reader.SelectVoice("Microsoft Zira Desktop");
```

To get the list of the voices currently installed:

```
foreach(var voice in reader.GetInstalledVoices()){
    Console.WriteLine(voice.VoiceInfo.Name);

}
```