# Text-To-Speech inventorying voices

Tags: .net, vb.net, text-to-speech

With the following code I can list all the voices installed in Windows (or so I thought):

```
Imports System.Speech.Synthesis
```

...

```
Dim sp As New SpeechSynthesizer

Each InstalledVoice As InstalledVoice In sp.GetInstalledVoices()
           ListOfInstalledVoices.Add(InstalledVoice)
Next

sp.Dispose()
```

The problem is that on my machine it only lists two voices (Microsoft David Desktop and Microsoft Zira Desktop) but when I go into the Windows Text-To-Speech settings there are five voices listed (David, Linda, Zira, Marc, and Richard).

Originally I thought it my have to do with 32bit vs 64bit (as referenced here: [SpeechSynthesizer doesn't get all installed voices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3208617/speechsynthesizer-doesnt-get-all-installed-voices)), but it does not (I tried compiling with x86 and x64 and there was no difference).

I also thought perhaps, Marc might be David with a different age setting, but could not tell because I can't change the age attribute on David (it is read only).

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit

It was suggested I use the speech sdk 11 / sdk11 runtime - However, trying to use sdk 11 / runtime made matters worse. I removed the reference to System.Speech and its associated imports, downloaded and installed Microsoft Speech Platform - Software Development Kit (SDK) (Version 11) microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27226 added the associated dll (64 bit) as a reference and added the 'Imports System.Speech.Synthesis', After this, there were no devices reported when I compiled as x64, x86 or AnyCPU. I then tried the same by downloading just the sdk11 runtime and including the dll that came with it. No love. Reverting back to the original reverted me back to my original problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install and use additional voices in SpeechSynthesizer()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31924110/how-to-install-and-use-additional-voices-in-speechsynthesizer)

Answer (score 0):

This will output a list of the text-to-speech voices via VB:

```
Imports System.Speech.Synthesis

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim synth As SpeechSynthesizer = New SpeechSynthesizer()
        For Each voice In synth.GetInstalledVoices()
            Console.WriteLine(voice.VoiceInfo.Name)
        Next
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module
```

I originally found this for C# [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26980895/change-output-voice-in-c-sharp). Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Thanks but sadly that did not do the trick, it only returned 2 of the five voices.